# Insert Document in ElastiSearch in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, lumen

I have created Index whenever a user is created.

```
PHP code

$params = [
'index' => 'my_index',
'body' => [
    'settings' => [
        'analysis' => [
            'analyzer' => [
                 'filter' => ['lowercase']
             ]
    ],
    'mappings' => [
       'meta' => [
        'properties' => [
            'first_name' => [
                'type' => 'keyword'
            ],
            'age' => [
                'type' => 'integer'
            ]
            'last_name' => [
                 'type' => 'text'
            ]
           ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
];
```

This is the index. How can I insert the value insert the value inside elastic in php ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/updating_documents.html